# Ubuntu Server 12.04 on a ssd & data on RAID HDD

Tags: installation, hard-drive, raid, ssd

I'm new so please forgive me if i'm posting against the rules or something like that.
I found some topics that are a bit related, but none with raid 10.

I'm going to switch from Windows server to Ubuntu 12.04 (finally !!!), but now I have a question:

I have a 128 GB SSD, that i want to use for the main OS, and I have four 1TB drives, that I want in a raid 10 configuration for all my data.

I already tried to install, but after the installation, i rebooted and then i get the raid configuration screen (that said that there aren't any raid drives), and then nothing but a black screen with a flickering cursor a the top left (as far as i know that means the isn't any OS detected).

So i booted in to recovery from the USB and from the [partition disk] menu, I see that my partition on the SSD is set to {not used}, but I'm sure I set it correctly before. The same is applying for the RAID volume.

What is the best thing I can do now ?

**EDIT:**
@psusi, htnx for your replay. In the Intel raid configuration manager, I added all the drives to a raid 10 (0+1) configuration, after that I started the installation and Ubuntu auto detected the raid and added it to my partitioning list. Then U just mounted the raid partition to /home and made 2 new partitions on my SSD (boot and swap) and mounted the boot part. on /

here is the output:

```
~ # dmraid -s
**** Group superset isw_hjabdiead
--> Superset
name   : isw_hjabdiead_Data
size   : 3711742464
stride : 128 
type   : raid01
status : ok
subset : 2
devs   : 4
spares : 0
```

Ps: sorry can't get that code block working correctly :p

Comment: It sounds like you are mixing up fakeraid and linux software raid.  Had you set up the ssd to act as a cache using the bios fakeraid before?  On the livecd, run `sudo dmraid -s` and edit the output into your question.

Comment: So you have it working now?  I would suggest avoiding the fakeraid stuff if you don't have to dual boot with Windows.  It isn't as well supported as Linux software raid.  I recently set up a 3 disk mdadm raid10 in the offset layout mode ( see the `-p o2` switch to `mdadm`, and you'll also want an 8 MB or so chunk size ), and it has the read performance of raid0, so that would make it about twice as fast as using the fakeraid.

Comment: no, it still isn't working, i tried re-installing a few times, with the "Ubuntu raid" and the Intel raid. But also, if I have a some sort of a dedicated raid chip on my motherboard, is isn't fake raid anymore ? or am I wrong ? my motherboard is a Supermicro X10-SLM-F

Comment: It isn't a dedicated raid chip.  It's the regular AHCI SATA controller built into the motherboard, and Intel has special bios extensions and Windows drivers to pretend that it's a hardware raid.  I suggest you blow away the raid in the bios, make sure that `dmraid -s` doesn't see it any more, and install from there.

Comment: okay, i figured it out. For some reason it was writing the EFI boot partition automatically to the raid array. So I just mounted an Gig partition on the ssd as EFI and it fixed everything. Thnx for you're help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, i figured it out. For some reason it was writing the EFI boot partition automatically to the raid array. So I just mounted an Gig partition on the ssd as EFI and it fixed everything.